# Performant Way To Select Most Recent Item Per Group In Django / Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a query performance issue that I'm trying to solve in Django.

**Environment:**

- Django 2.2
- Python 3.6
- Postgresql 11

**Example Models:**

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    # ...

class VendingMachine(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey("MyApp.Location", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    # ...

class Vend(models.Model):
    vending_machine = models.ForeignKey("MyApp.VendingMachine", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    vend_start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    # ...
```

I am trying to get a list of the most recent Vends per VendingMachine.

There are a couple approaches I've taken, but they either don't quite work in the setup and requirements that I have, or take WAY too long to execute.

**Version 1:**

```py
Vend.objects.filter(pk__in=Subquery(Vend.objects.order_by().values('vendingmachine__location__id', 'vendingmachine__id').annotate(max_id=Max('id')).values('max_id')))
```

This version is super fast. However, it only works if the Vend IDs are in chronological order. The data is inserted into the database in a random order, so this doesn't work.

**Version 2:**

```py
Vend.objects.all().order_by('vendingmachine_id', '-vend_start_time').distinct('vendingmachine_id')
```

This version takes 12-15 seconds to execute, and since since it is being run through a paginator, the query is executed twice (once for the count, the second time to get the objects and slicing), so the page takes about 30 seconds to load which is way too long.
The other issue with this version is that the results can't be sorted (except in Python) once they are returned since it relies on the order_by sorting the vend_start_time for selecting the last one.

**Version 3:**

```py
vend_sub_qs = Vend.objects.filter(vendingmachine_id=OuterRef("vendingmachine_id")).order_by("-vend_start_time").values_list("id", flat=True)[:1]
vend_qs = Vend.objects.filter(pk__in=Subquery(vend_sub_qs)).order_by("-vend_start_time")
vending_machines = VendingMachine.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("vend_set", queryset=vend_qs))
```

I tried a different approach here ending up with a list of Vending Machines with their latest Vends prefetched. This doesn't work well because I really do need to end with a QuerySet of Vends.
This was also extremely slow taking around 45 seconds to execute.

**Summary:**

It is important that I end with a QuerySet of the Vend object and that it can be sorted by different fields on Vend.

It'd be ideal if this could execute in 5 seconds or less.

It is ok to use Django functions that are Postgres specific.
Raw SQL is an option too, if a QuerySet can still be obtained at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using custom SQL.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

**Raw SQL:**

```py
vends = Vend.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM "myapp_vend" WHERE (vendingmachine_id, vend_start_time) IN (SELECT vendingmachine_id, max(vend_start_time) FROM "myapp_vend" GROUP BY vendingmachine_id)')
```

This executed in 2 seconds and properly got me a QuerySet of the Vend objects.
However, it was a RawQuerySet that doesn't support order_by and annotation calls. Since I am passing the QuerySet to a library that applies ordering and annotations for table display, I needed a normal QuerySet.

**Custom SQL:**

```py
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM "myapp_vend" WHERE (vendingmachine_id, vend_start_time) IN (SELECT vendingmachine_id, max(vend_start_time) FROM "myapp_vend" GROUP BY vendingmachine_id)') 
    ids = [x[0] for x in cursor.fetchall()]
vends = Vend.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

Only selecting the id allowed me to then execute a normal Django filter statement selecting on the ids returned by the Custom SQL. This gave me a normal QuerySet that could be passed on to the library that added order_by and annotations, but does require two queries to be run.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the way you fetch your results. means, Instead of querying `Vend` go and fetch `VendingMachines` and order it's related vends by time

```
class VendingMachine(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey("MyApp.Location", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    # ...

# Note I added 'related_name' in here
class Vend(models.Model):
    vending_machine = models.ForeignKey("MyApp.VendingMachine", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='vends')
    vend_start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    # ...
```

Then your query shall look as follows:

```
vending_machines = VendingMachine.objects.prefetch_related('vends').all()
```

Then apply your preferred ordering and filters on `VendingMachine` or `Vend`s for each machine.

Example if you're iterating over your vending machines you would do something like

```
for machine in vending_machines:
    most_recent_vends = machine.vends.order_by('-vend_start_time')
```